# Weaknesses of my database schema design?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-model

So I have a database schema of a relation below for table [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYkV6.png) :

ABC(doc-name, doc-gender, registration[_num, qualification, pat-name, pat-gender,
DOB, address, phone-num, appoint-date,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYkV6.png) appoint-time, type)

What are the weaknesses of my design?

Comment: Is there a primary key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the Weaknesses of my database schema design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49441367/what-are-the-weaknesses-of-my-database-schema-design)